# Angular share an object which requires an async operation to initialize

Tags: angular, http, service, async-await

In an angular project, I have a logger class for which I need to retrieve its parameters using a http request. After initializing the Logger, all components plus services are supposed to use that logger.

I was wondering what the best practice here?

What I did is that I declared a service to make a http request:

```html
  async getLogger(): Promise<Logger> {
    if (!this.initialized) {
      const data = await this.http
        .get<IClientConfiguration>(this.configUrlPath)
        .toPromise();
      this.ddta = new Logger(
        data.apiUrl
      );
      this.initialized = true;
      return this.ddta;
    }
    return this.ddta;
  }
```

Then in every components I injected that service in the constructor and then in onInit:

```html
this.logger = await this.loggerService.getLogger();
```

I am not sure it is the way to do this. On the other hand how I can use this logger in on other services?

Comment: Why dont you use observables instead of promises?

Answer (score 0):

One issue that could present with this is if multiple components were loaded at the same time and called `getLogger()` before the http finished. In this case they would all hit the `!initialized` resulting in more requests and multiple loggers.

One option would be to cache the observable itself:

```
logger$: Observable<Logger>;

async getLogger(): Promise<Logger> {
    if (!this.logger$) {
        const data = await this.http
            .get<IClientConfiguration>(this.configUrlPath)
            .pipe(map(data=> new Logger(data.apiUrl)));
    }
    
    return this.logger$.toPromise(); // firstValueFrom(this.logger$) is the newer way
}
```

> I did not test this code, just typed it so it might not be exact.

Reference:

https://indepth.dev/posts/1248/fastest-way-to-cache-for-lazy-developers-angular-with-rxjs

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I am using that logger almost for all components and services, I think I need to wait until the Logger object is received. How I can wait on an observable both on components and services?

Comment: This caching will have an async return that you can always await and the response will be that one logger.